# How to create Idle time?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch file program where if you open a mspaint.exe, if its idle for 10 seconds the program will close automatically. I have created this:

```
@echo off

:Start
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq mspaint.exe" | findstr "mspaint.exe" >nul  
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" GOTO Running
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" GOTO NotRunning

:Running
***::Check if idle***

GOTO Terminate

:NotRunning
 GOTO EOF

:Terminate
timeout 5
taskkill /im mspaint.exe /f
ECHO Paint has been terminated due to inactivity
PAUSE

:EOF
EXIT
```

I have trouble finding the idle syntax(seems it doesn't exist), is there another way to make the idle time work? And since this is my first time creating a batch file, I really need a helping hand here.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want to hear, but the one that you need. The only way to monitor another process for activity is to install a window hook, but that's going to require a much lower level language (C or C++).

If that doesn't put you off then start with the Microsoft [Hooks Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx) and post further questions. Good luck (you'll probably need it).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but that seems complicated. I used SCHTASKS instead and it worked :)